# Unknown Return Types from SQL Queries?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application which has methods that pull T SQL queries from a database table:

[image]

```
  public List<AwardsChartParameters> GetAwardsChartParameters(string country, string articleType)
    {                    
         var query = (from a in _Context.tbQueryTable
                      where a.ArticleType == ArticleType
                      select a.ColSelection + " " + a.FromTable + " " + a.whereclause + " " + a.orderBY);

         string queryResult = query.FirstOrDefault().ToString();

         return ((IObjectContextAdapter)_Context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AwardsChartParameters>(queryResult).ToList();
    }
```

So depending on the ArticleType passed in as a parameter from the UI, returns one of several result sets from a pivot query defined in the table.

I am currently trying to write a class for each possible result set e.g.

```
public class AwardsChartParameters
{
    public string operator_int_name { get; set; }
    public int countAll { get; set; }
}
```

This specific query in the table will return a list of string & int therefore I can pull in the results to my `List<AwardsChartParameters>` & chart them in my UI. This way I will need a class to hold all possible result sets from the table as the table grows.

Is there any way of creating a dynamic list or class which is built at run time depending on the result set from the query. For example the user's 1st query may return a list of strings, the 2nd query returns a list of strings & ints?

I am using Entity Framework therefore mapping entities to concrete classes in the sql Server db in other parts of the code however with result sets from queries in a table like this, I have concrete dependencies to the results structure & I am beginning to smell bad code...

Comment: If you move the query itself into a stored procedure with a few params, instead of generating the query programatically, I feel it would get rid of the code smell.Assuming this is possible (you would probably need to use some dynamic SQL in the SP), it would encapsulate the logic in one place and EF will even generate the classes you need for you: [Calling Stored Procedures from EF](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/calling-stored-procedures-from-entity-framework.aspx)